# UITableView swipe to delete with no confirmation

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Quick question about swipe to delete feature in UITableView - is there a way to just go ahead and delete the row without showing the Delete button and waiting for user's confirmation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement your custom UITableViewCell and make use of [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You'll have to write all your logic (protocol, delegate etc.) on your own, but you will have it totally customizable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by your own code.

Take one button and on click of that delete the selected row from UiTableView

Comment: I'd like deleting to be accessed using the swipe gesture, not a button. Kind of like it does by default, but without the confirmation 'Delete' button that usually shows up after swiping. Was wondering if there is a way to do this without reimplementing all of the gestures in UITableView.

Comment: I don't have idea for that but i think you can do it using touch events. But i have never try that.