# UITableView disable "delete" confirmation

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

This is similar to questions that are asking how to swipe/delete without confirmation:

[UITableView swipe to delete with no confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230615/uitableview-swipe-to-delete-with-no-confirmation)

My tableview has cells with UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete set.  When the tableview is in editing mode, the cells display a red circle icon with a '-' inside.  To delete the cell, the user taps the red circle, and a Delete button appears.  The user must then tap Delete which triggers `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`.

Some of my rows support UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert.  In this scenario the cells display a green circle icon with a '+' inside.  Tapping the circle invokes `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` immediately.

I'd like to have `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` invoked immediately when the user taps the initial red-circle icon.  That is, no delete-button step.

Any ideas?

Is there a way to provide custom editing controls that slide in from the left like delete/insert?  If so, perhaps I could use this mechanism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with one solution, but it risks rejection.  (Does checking for an undocumented class by classname constitute a sdk-agreement violation?)

Perhaps someone can improve on this?

Basically, in the context of my custom UITableViewCell, I watch for the delete button (not a UIButton, unfortunately) to be added, then invoke it's UIControlEventTouchUpInside action.  With a bit of delay so the animations work out:

```
- (void) addSubview:(UIView *)view
{
    if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl"]) 
    {

        UIControl* c = (UIControl*)view;

        NSArray* actions = [c actionsForTarget: self forControlEvent: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self performSelector: NSSelectorFromString( [actions lastObject] ) withObject: view afterDelay: .25];

        return;
    }

    [super addSubview: view];
}
```

Comment: I'd be curious to hear if this got rejected or not when you submit it.

Comment: Yeah, I'll post here once it's accepted/rejected.  I may try to rework this to remove the UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl classname - just haven't decided on the best way to do that yet.

Comment: Could you please let us know whether it was accepted or rejected?

Comment: was not rejected.  however it breaks (unsurprisingly) in iOS7.