# How to "do not display" the (confirmation) delete button on an UITableView when deleting?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I can not find the anwser over the net, I don't know even it's possible to do this,

Is it possible to do not have the delete button (at your right)  in edition mode when you try to delete one item?

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230615/uitableview-swipe-to-delete-with-no-confirmation

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Detemine if the user can edit the comment.
    if (something) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But in this case I can not delete at all that line. What I need, is to do not have the delete button at the right side for confirmation of the delete when you push the one at the left.

Comment: My goal is to replace the minus button by the plus button without confirmation, I mean as soon as i  push the minus button.